# prevent function onclick but keeping it in the code | bookmarklet

Tags: onclick, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet I want people to drag to bookmarks bar. The hings is I'd like to prevent the function is fired if accidentally the bookmarklet is clicked in the web page. How can I do so?

Thanks

```
    <div id="bookmarklet">
      <a href="javascript:(function(){alert('mimmo');});" class="title">Bookmarklet</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<div id="bookmarklet">
  <a href="javascript:(function(){alert('mimmo');})()" onclick="return false" class="title">Bookmarklet</a>
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<div id="bookmarklet">
  <a href="javascript:(function(){alert('mimmo');})()" onclick="alert('Drag and drop this link onto browser toolbar to install');return false" class="title">Bookmarklet</a>
</div>
```

I've corrected the `HREF` script code since the original would declare a function without executing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="alert('this is a bookmarklet');return false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bookmarklet a').mousedown(function() {
        $('#bookmarklet a').attr("href", "alert('mimmo')")
    });
    $('#bookmarklet a').mouseup(function() {
        $('#bookmarklet a').attr("href", "#")
    });
</script>
```